# Vowpal Wabbit python library for text binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

With [pyvw](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/python), I'm implementing a spam-filter-like binary classifier. Most python implementations are wrappers and create text files and use the command line options. But there some [good documentation here](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/python/VW_in_Python.ipynb).

I would like code to look like this.

```
import pyvw
examples = []
examples[1] = (1, "This is spam.")
examples[2] = (-1, "This is ham.")

vw = pyvw.vw("--passes 300 --ngram 3 --cache_file test.cache ")
for text in examples:
    # using dictionary instead of string " |s This is spam."
    ex = vw.example({"s": text[1]}) 
    ex.set_label_string(str(text[0])) 
    ex.learn()

test = vw.example(" | This is also spam.")
test.learn() 
print test.get_updated_prediction() #<-- usually 0.0
print test.get_simplelabel_prediction() #<-- the same for every prediction?
test = vw.example(" | This is certainly ham.")
test.learn() 
print test.get_updated_prediction() #<-- usually 0.0
print test.get_simplelabel_prediction() #<-- the same for every prediction?
```

Here's how I implemented a SequenceLabeler

```
class SequenceLabeler(pyvw.SearchTask):
    def __init__(self, vw, sch, num_actions):
        # you must must must initialize the parent class
        # this will automatically store self.sch <- sch, self.vw <- vw
        pyvw.SearchTask.__init__(self, vw, sch, num_actions)
        # set whatever options you want
        sch.set_options(sch.AUTO_HAMMING_LOSS | sch.AUTO_CONDITION_FEATURES)

    def _run(self, sentence):   # it's called _run to remind you that you shouldn't call it directly!
        output = []
        #for n in range(len(sentence)):
            # pos, word = sentence[n]
            # use "with...as..." to guarantee that the example is finished properly
            #with self.vw.example({'s': [sentence]}) as ex:
            count = 0
            with self.vw.example({'s': sentence[1]}) as ex:
                # label 0 is not allowed for multiclass.  Valid labels are {1,k}
                pred = self.sch.predict(examples=ex, my_tag=count+1, oracle=sentence[0] + 1) # 
                output.append(pred)
                count += 1
            return output

    sequenceLabeler = vw.init_search_task(SequenceLabeler)   
    for i in xrange(10):
        sequenceLabeler.learn(examples)
```

What am I missing? The [examples in the wiki](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/hal3/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/python/Learning_to_Search.ipynb) are good, but don't cover this specific use case.

Notes/questions:

1. Is creating a  `SequenceLabeler(pyvw.SearchTask)` required? Otherwise `example()` doesn't seem to have a predict(), where as `sch` does. How would I call `predict()` without `sch`?
2. to construct an `vw.example()`, could we use a dictionary of features like {"s": "Here is the text of some spam."}, where s is the feature label?
   And if I am in a `SequenceLabeler` do I assigned the class (1 for spam) to the "oracle" param of `sch.predict()`? If I am not in SequenceLabeler, where do I set the class? via `set_label_string()`?
3. How do I explicitly set the vw to understand it's a binary classification? Should the labels for a binary classification problem be 0,1 or -1,1? I get the error  `"# label 0 is not allowed for multiclass.  Valid labels are {1,k}"`. I can easily avoid this error by shifting labels. Is this a data format issue, or am I missing a parameter? Also, seems like some documentation says I can use 0,1 where others suggest -1,1 for labels.

---

**EDIT**
[Updates from the mailing list](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/topics/5478) answer #1 and #3 above, which is that answers must be -1, 1, and a search/sequencelabeler are not needed.

Comment: Note that `--adaptive` is on by default, but specifying it explicitly deactivates other improvements over plain SGD (`--normalized` and `--invariant`). Are you sure you want this?

Comment: `"0 | This is also spam."` label 0 is not allowed for binary classification. If you don't know the correct label in prediction, just omit it: ``" | This is also spam."``

Comment: I think the main problem here is that we are missing a documentation/tutorial on how to use VW from Python on basic tasks (regression, classification,...). There is only the ipynb on VW's Learning2Search from Python (which is not suitable for spam classification).

Comment: Thanks again Martin. Happy to update this post, as we go. Can one assume no TFIDF pre-filtering?

Comment: VW has no TFIDF because: 1) it is not possible to implement in fully online fasion, 2) it is not needed with the default adaptive (AdaGrad) update, at least in the cases I have seen.

Comment: Thanks. Cool. Older tutorials for Vowpal suggest using another lib like scikitlearns tfdif to create features before handing to Vowpal. Wasn't aware of #2. If there's a few more steps I am missing, I'd be happy to write an end user tutorial.

Comment: TF-IDF can be used both for feature selection and for assigning feature values (instead of raw number of occurrences). What I meant was that the TF-IDF feature values are not so needed (and helpful) with the adaptive update as they would be with plain `--sgd` update. Of course, they may still help a bit. As for the feature selection (filtering), you can use L1 regularization for this in VW, but here I have no experience with comparison with TF-IDF.

Comment: For binary classification, you should use `--loss_function=logistic`. If you want -1 and +1 output labels, then use `--binary`, if you want probabilities as output labels, then use `--link=logistic`.